# MAX EXECUTION TIME exceeded in long polling

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, comet, long-polling

I am trying to get latest messages from the MySQL table using long-polling .

Here if i haven't got any new messages i am making script `sleep()` for 10 seconds.

But in the worst case scenario if i don't receive any new messages for *10 minutes* the script will say `max_execution_time` exceeded.

How will i fix this . Can anyone say where i am going wrong.

**PS** - I don't want to use Websockets for now atleast.

**pullmessage.php**

```
    $notyetgot = true;
    $data_msg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE  message_id>".$latest." ");
    $n  = mysqli_num_rows($data_msg);
    if($n > 0){$notyetgot=false;}
    while($notyetgot){
        sleep(10);

        $data_msg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id>".$latest." ");

        $n  = mysqli_num_rows($data_msg);       
        if($n > 0){$notyetgot = false;}

    }
 ...
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Redesign the flow so that the web server is not sitting there waiting with an 'active' thread.

Comment: can u clarify @RickJames what is supposed to be redesigned ? can you give a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, I hope I am understanding correctly the purpose of your code.)

PHP is designed to execute on-demand.  A request comes in, it briefly does something, then goes away.  To, instead, have it sitting there waiting for something is "wrong".

If, for example, you are building a feature similar to stackoverflow's "recent inbox messages", that is probably implemented by client-side Javascript code, which *is* "sitting there waiting" (waiting for the user to close the page).

Stack overflow is impressive with how many bits of information it puts on the page, and does it reasonably rapidly.  A lot of sites perform poorly on less complex pages.

Back to the JS "solution".  The JS code would periodically send an AJAX request to a PHP(?) page on some SO server.  PHP would start, connect to the database, fetch the stuff requested, send it back to the client, and die.  Then the JS would modify the DOM, and poof, the 'inbox' turns red and the number increments by 1.

It's a lot of work, and a lot of moving parts.  But I think the *initiation* of the task starts on the client, not the server.

Note, also, that once PHP goes away, it has no way to reconnect to the client's web page.  AJAX serves that purpose, but works in the "opposite direction".

Comment: you did understood my question. So making a ajax call to server every `10-20 seconds` per user(assuming hundereds of thousands of them online at same time) is just too many requests to the server.

Comment: How does stackoverflow solves it ? I dont see too many requests from stackoverflow still it manages to show the recent inbox messages,notifications quite fast  ? @rickjames

Comment: There are many ways they might survive the onslaught.  One is to have lots of machines with web servers, and have them read from lots of MySQL Slaves.  With that layout (and enough money to afford it), you can achieve unlimited scaling.

Comment: Another technique is to use memcached (or other non-MySQL, web-based, caching mechanism).  That would contain the 'answer' to the AJAX call.  But that cache would need to be 'invalidated' whenever a message comes in.  An extra layer, with extra complication, but faster.

Comment: According to your experience can you tell how much request per minute to a server each client must sent (assuming the server to contain ~ 1 million clients online at same time) in most probalby the cheapest of VPS @rickjames

Comment: Apache can handle dozens, maybe hundreds of requests per second.  Each MySQL slave can handle thousands of _trivial_ SELECTs per second.  There are faster web servers, but they may no support PHP and MySQL calls.  I recommend some light-weight caching layer, plus code to "push" changes to it.  That is, a new message would (somehow) update (or simply) invalidate all the cache entries relating to the message count.  50K/sec is a lot.  Sorry, I don't have all the details.

Comment: Back-of-the-envelope calculations says that the 300K posts tagged [mysql] averages only 10K web pages asking for AJAX updates.  That's a lot less than your 1M.  Suggest that you implement something, but plan to replace it in a few months.  Then get real metrics and look for better system designs.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can run the script from shell where max_execution_time defaults to 0 (infinite).

```
php pullmessage.php
```